# PHP: multiple AND conditions in MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out why i cannot run a multiple `AND` conditions in mysql query.

basically this is my code:

```
SELECT id, category_name, url, category_name_unedit FROM mytable WHERE category_name='Girls Clothes' AND category_name='Boys Clothes' GROUP BY category_name
```

the code above doesn't return anything but when I run the code individually like this:

```
SELECT id, category_name, url, category_name_unedit FROM mytable WHERE category_name='Girls Clothes' GROUP BY category_name
```

or like this:

```
SELECT id, category_name, url, category_name_unedit FROM mytable WHERE category_name='Boys Clothes' GROUP BY category_name
```

then it works fine!

This is such a basic issue and unfortunately i cannot figure out how to resolve it.

could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: Girls clothes OR Boys clothes?

Comment: @H.HISTORY In that case, we need more information. Could you give some sample output of your 2 working queries?

Comment: You should describe what you want to accomplish.  Sample data and desired results are quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the logic of the query is off. If you think about it, you can't have a category name where its name is Girls Clothes AND Boys Clothes. However, you can have a result where the name is Girls Clothes OR Boys Clothes.

The query should look like:

```
SELECT id, 
category_name, 
url, 
category_name_unedit 
FROM mytable 
WHERE category_name='Girls Clothes' 
OR category_name='Boys Clothes' 
GROUP BY category_name
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you want urls that are in both categories.  If so:

```
SELECT url
FROM mytable 
WHERE category_name IN ('Girls Clothes', 'Boys Clothes')
GROUP BY url
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

If you just want to check for either category, then use `IN` in your query (or `OR`).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, category_name, url, category_name_unedit FROM mytable WHERE category_name='Girls Clothes' AND category_name='Boys Clothes' GROUP BY category_name
```

Because it is not possible for one item to have 2 `category_name`s.

What you probably intend is to find it if it is EITHER "Girls Clothes" or "Boys Clothes". In that case, you would use OR instead of AND.

```
SELECT id, category_name, url, category_name_unedit FROM mytable WHERE category_name='Girls Clothes' OR category_name='Boys Clothes' GROUP BY category_name
```

Comment: Ugh. Need to check out first, second and third normal forms for database normalization / design.  Hint. Boys clothes. Girls clothes. Unisex kids clothes